# How do I ingest float from BigQuery into featurestore?

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai

I have a `float` type field in BQ. I try to ingest this into a `double` type field in featurestore but get:

```
Source schema does not match the expected schema for this import. 
Missing fields in source: feature_field. Type mismatches in source: 
Expected type and mode [STRING, NULLABLE] for BQ_field, but got [FLOAT, ].
```

How can I import it?